# SignalR connection failed: WebSocket connection failed:. Error: Failed to start the connection: null

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

My frontend console is showing this error : **WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:5001/grouphub' failed:. Error: Failed to start the connection: null**

The startup.ConfigureServices code is :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
                              options =>
                              {
                                  options.AllowAnyOrigin();
                                  options.AllowAnyHeader();
                                  options.AllowAnyMethod();
                              });
        });
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddMvc();
}
```

The code for the startup.Configure is:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCustomMiddleware();
        //app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseFileServer();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<GroupHub>("/grouphub");
        });
    }
```

The code for the client is :

```
public startConnection() {
this.collectionHubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("https://localhost:5001/grouphub", {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  }).build();
this.collectionHubConnection.start()
  .then(() => console.log("collection SIGNALR CONN DONE"))
  .catch(err => console.log("collection SIGNALR ERROR:" + err));
}
loadPatientCollection() {
this.collectionHubConnection.on("patientcollist", (data) => {
  this.insurancedb1 = data
  console.log("patient collection data", data);
})
}
```

I am not gettting any CORS error and also when I let signalR to choose the transport type it still not works.

Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: Are you also seeing CORS errors in the frontend console?

Comment: In your code, we can find you restrict the client to only use the `WebSockets` as transports, if you try to use another transport or let SignalR automatically chooses the best transport method, does it can connect to hub well?